# how to avoid changing value of const in C

Tags: c

Hi, I am a beginner to the programming world,
i want to know how to avoid changing the value of a const variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 const int i = 10;
 int * p = &i;
 *p = 20;
 printf("*p = %d\ni = %d\n", *p,i);
 printf("%u\n%u\n",&i, p);
 return 0;
}
```

here in above program i am getting only warning but no error while i am assigning value to const field via pointer, but when i print the out isn't different:

```
*p = 20
i = 10
3210723532
3210723532
```

so then what is the use of getting pointer to const when it is not change able.

Comment: gcc v4.5.2 on linux gives me the output of `*p = 20
i = 20`, It's strange that your output is different.

Comment: Just never ignore a warning. The C language only specifies that a "diagnostic" must be issued. Warnings are as severe as errors.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Some warnings are *not* required by the language at all though, and are simply an annoyance (for example "*Suggest parantheses around assignment used as truth value*").

Comment: @majie: Try with optimisation.

Comment: @caf, the one that you mention is certainly a matter of taste (I would never see this one, I guess :) but for starters in C they are *all* to be considered, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard uses only the term "diagnostic". There is no distinction between warnings and errors.

The conversion of `const int *` to `int *` without a cast is a constraint violation that requires a diagnostic.

This puts it in the same category as a syntax error: your code is not a valid ISO C program and the behavior is undefined if it is translated anyway and executed.

Unfortunately, many compilers do not distinguish required diagnostics from extra diagnostics that they add, and what is worse, they sometimes required diagnostics as warnings. This is allowed: the C standard doesn't say that programs which require a diagnostic must be prevented from translating and executing. By emitting a warning, a compiler satisfies the requirement for diagnosis and that is that.

Another issue is that many C compilers do not even accept the standard ISO C dialect unless they are asked to, but instead accept their own dialect, which may have nonconforming (i.e. not backward compatible) extensions.

The GNU C compiler understands a C dialect called GNU C 89, if you don't give it any dialect options.

So, ironically, in this dialect, it is a mere warning to convert `const int *` to `int *` without a cast, whereas certain legal C90 programs are completely rejected.

So basically you always have to understand how to control the input dialect of your compiler, and follow up on all the warnings, which you have to understand, by yourself, whether they are real violations of the language, or just the whims of the compiler writers ("suggest parentheses around this expression").

It's not a bad idea to compile with `gcc -Wall -W -ansi` (if you're programming in the C90;  or `-std=c99` instead of `ansi` for C99) and ensure that there are no warnings. Not even the stylistic ones which suggest extra parentheses and such. If you're not disciplined enough to follow up on warnings add `-Werror` to turn them into errors that fail your build. Some would also recommend `-pedantic`.

If you follow this discipline, the subversion of a `const int` will not sneak into your codebase.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the compiler will give the warning because of the code `int * p = &i;`

and the value of i is not changed, because the compile optimize the code,I use the gcc to test the code :

if I use the `gcc -O0 const.c -o const` , `O0` represents no compiler optimization, the result is

```
*p = 20
i = 20
1114013412
1114013412
```

but when i use the `gcc -O2 const.c -o const`, `O2`represents the compiler optimization, the result is

```
*p = 20
i = 10
1262279764
1262279764
```

So, the compiler knows that the type of `i` is `const` , and replaces `i` by `10` at compile time itself, and hence the code becomes

```
 printf("*p = %d\ni = %d\n", *p,10);
```

Also you can use `gcc -S const.c` to look into the assembly code.

Answer (score 2):

The C language standard (almost) never requires compilers to *reject* incorrect code.  If you write something illegal and the compiler merely warns you about it, the compiler has done its job as far as the C language standard is concerned.

You need to take compiler warnings very seriously.  If your code compiles without warnings *or* errors, then it's probably legal (which doesn't mean it will actually work!).

Comment: While you're technically correct, what OP should do instead is get a better compiler.

Comment: is there any way so that i want to avoid using pointer to change const variable value.

Comment: @avakar: That may not be practical.  But gcc, though it issues warnings for a lot of invalid constructs, has the `-Werror` option that turns warnings into fatal errors.

Comment: @user954299: If you don't want to change a `const` object, then just don't change it.  The compiler warned you about it.  Change your code so you don't get any warnings, and you (probably) won't be changing any `const`s.  If you change `int *p = &i;` to `const int *p = &i;`, you'll avoid the warning on that line and get a new diagnostic on `*p = 20;`.  Bottom line: Take warnings very seriously.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't realize that gcc will only issue a warning (it won't in C++ mode...). I guess there's a compatibility reason for it. Maybe `-ansi` would turn it into an error?

Comment: @avakar: C and C++ are different languages. In C, `const` means "read-only"; in C++ (I think) it really means constant.

Comment: @pmg, they are, but `const` means the nearly same thing in both languages (there's a tiny difference in default linkage of global const objects).

Comment: @pmg: In C++, unlike in C, `const int answer = 42;` makes `answer` a constant expression. But both allow `const int r = rand();`, and obviously `r` can't be a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `#define` instead.

Objects declared `const` are not constant in the english meaning of the term, they are "read-only".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 #define I 10
 int * p = &I; // illegal &I
 *p = 20;
 printf("*p = %d\nI = %d\n", *p,I);
 printf("%u\n%u\n",&I, p); // illegal &I
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, objects declared const are constant in the English meaning of the term.  What the program is doing is undefined behavior as a result of breaking a rule for which a diagnostic is required (and was issued!) Recommending `#define` instead of const is poor advice. You duped the poor newbie into accepting a crap answer.

Comment: Oh, and you can `#undef I` and then `#define I 13`. Is that the English meaning of constant?

Comment: Beware also that `I` is a predefined macro in `<complex.h>`.