# Why can a const value not be changed in C++ but in C?

Tags: c++, c

In an interview, I was asked to change constant value in CPP, but I said in CPP it is not possible but in c it is possible using pointer.

Interviewer said that using CPP it is possible and asked me to try but I couldn't and I came back to my room and tried again but what I figured out that I was able to change in C but same code was getting error when compiled as C++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    const int i=5;
    int *p;
    p=&i;
    *p=8;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

This code is changing the constant value of i in c but when I compile in CPP then 
I get an error:

```
 invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'
```

Comment: This isn't your real code.

Comment: What's CPP? Do you mean C++? You can't legitimately change a constant in either language (although you can use an evil cast to write code that tries to, with undefined behaviour). Certainly, your example shouldn't compile in C or C++.

Comment: http://ideone.com/8EvEcr you can't chane the read only variable.

Comment: It depends on what possible means. It might be possible in both although it is not standard compliant. It depends on where the compiler allocated the constant variable.

Comment: How are you compiling this for C (ie., what compiler toolchain and what version of the toolchain)?

Comment: Are you sure that pointer has `const` modifier too (not only `i` variable) ?

Comment: "It is possible" is quite misleading, because it is *undefined behaviour*. It is possible to get the code to compile, but the resulting program is broken.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi:: Thanks. fixed:: http://ideone.com/lmAP1g

Comment: I couldn't get why all people are bother about error I made .I am new here and searching for my 1st job i know my question is not countable at any level but i m sure every one was at mine level one day. everyone is just voting me down apart from helping me out.I am sure all are concern about getting anyhow more and more reputation.

Comment: Although code is wrong, but question is good.

Comment: @user3632872 The error has been made by the interviewer if he / she claims that it "is possible" - as other comments point out. This question is voted down because it won't help anyone here. But these are two independent issues.

Comment: You write "I was able to change [the value, -ps] in c but same code was **not** getting error in CPP." [Emphasis by me.] I understand that you **did** get an error in C++, as indicated by the error message you cited. Then the "not" in "not getting error in CPP" is misplaced, right? Because you _did_ get an error?

Comment: The above code is not producing any error in c but same code if i try in c++ then i get error can anyone please explain?

Comment: @user3632872; If everyone here is telling you that this code would't even compile in C, then why you are repeating that *it is not producing any error in C*?

Comment: @hacks I tired it is compiling please try it compiling

Comment: @user3632872 This is a "mistake" in the *compiler* itself. The C compiler is not following the defined rules! After all, the compiler is also a program written by somebody :). Whereas, the C++ compiler is actually following proper rules to give you an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your error, the actual program must have been the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    const int i=5;
    int *p;
    p=&i;
    *p=8;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

This produces a warning with gcc:

> warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type

and an error with g++:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'

So, let's change the title of your question to a better one:

> Why does C allow conversion from `const int *` to `int *`, but C++ doesn't?

The reason why one gives a warning and another gives an error is not because one allows you to discard `const` qualifier and the other doesn't. It's merely because the C standard leaves such incorrect actions as undefined behavior, while the C++ standard specifically marks it as an error. Either way, doing this is wrong.

You can read [this similar question asking why this is possible in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10085961/912144).

Comment: With `pedantic-errors` switch `gcc` produces: `error: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type`.

Answer (score 1):

What I think interviewer wanted this:

```
int n = 0;
int const *p = &n;
```

The expression `&n` has type “pointer to `int`.” The declaration for `p` converts `&n` to type “pointer to `const int`,” adding a `const` qualifier in the process. This is a valid qualification conversion. This conversion in no way invalidates `n`’s declaration. **The program can still use `n` to alter the `int` object**, even if it can’t use `*p` for the
same purpose.

```
*p = 5; // wrong
```

But

```
n = 5; // OK
```

now `*p` is `5` although it is `const` type!

Now try to run this code in GCC or g++, it will work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    const int *p;
    p=&n;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    n = 5;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** The only way to change the value of `const` qualified object in C and C++ both is, change the value in the initialization statement:

```
const int i = 5 ---> const int i = 8
```

Comment: There is no constant value in your code : pointers-to-const designate _readonly_ values, not _constant_ values (yep, that's misleading).

Comment: @Quentin; In my code `*p` is `const`. It is not misleading. And `const` in fact doesn't meant *constant* value.

Comment: NO actually const int n=0 not a const pointer and i am suppose to change this value in c++ .In c it is possible

Comment: @haccks (Please bear with the trouble I encounter explaining such subtleties in a foreign language): the interviewer mentioned a constant value, which is a value whose type is const (i.e `const int n`). p, on the other hand, does not somehow transform n into a constant, but provides read-only access to it.

Comment: @Quentin; Yes. But if I ask you that what is the type of `*p` then what will your answer?

Comment: @haccks int const&, or at least its C equivalent. But that's a side-effect of p being const, not n being const. While you have crafted a good example of why const pointers are not pointers to constants, OP is asking about an actual constant (and forcing assignment thereof).

Comment: it is pointer that is holding address of constant interger and with the help of pointer ,const value is changed in c but not in c++

Comment: @Quentin; Then the only possible way is change the value in the initialization statement: `const int i = 5` ---> `const int i = 8` ;)

Comment: @haccks Yep, and of course this stands for both C and C++. Therefore, someone should hire another interviewer.

Comment: @Quentin; Yes. Agreed :)

Comment: @hacks const int i=5  const int i=8 will give error as redefinition of i

Comment: @user3632872; I said *change* the value. I am not telling you to redefine

Answer (score 0):

This is why [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) exists, I believe the interviewer asked this because they have to deal with poorly designed library code they have no control over, however normally you shouldn't have to resort to using it in production.

Comment: Here the object itself is declared const, not the pointer/reference. `const_cast` can remove const-ness from the pointer, but if you try to modify the pointed-to const object, the result is *undefined behavior*.